# "homotopy sphere" assumption in Poincare Conjecture

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

For 3-dim Poincare Conjecture, the assumption is 'simply connected'. 
I am wondering whether simply connectedness assumption in 3-dim implies the same homotopy groups as the 3-sphere?

or If we switch the assumption of 'simply connected' to 'homotopy 3-sphere', would it be easier to proof Poincare Conjecuture.

Comment: *Please* do double check your typing: the title of your question is the very first thing people see!

Comment: Yes, in dimension three a closed simply connected 3-manifold is a homotopy sphere. This comes from Poincare duality.

Comment: I know $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ can be derived from Poincare duality, but how to derive $\pi_n$ for $n\ge 4$?


Comment: You look at the map $S^3 \rightarrow M$ generating $\pi_3M = H_3M$ (Hurewicz) and show it induces an isomorphism on cohomology for $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. The result follows by a version of Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: Despite the editing, the question still asks about the "same homopoy groups"


Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the fifth paragraph of

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/3Msurvey.pdf